# :after and :hover issue, do not affect whole element

Tags: css

I have this code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QdQEQW

As you can see, if you hover over "Dropdown" it also changes the background color of "V", the :after part. I do not want that. Simple. But I just can't get it done. I've googled and tried and tried but I just cant figure out how.

I've tried a bunch of different, variations, eg

```
.onclick-menu:hover.onclick-menu:after {
background: blue;
}

.onclick-menu:after:hover {
background: blue;
}

.onclick-menu:hover > onclick-menu:after:hover {
background: blue;
}

.onclick-menu:hover + onclick-menu:hover:after {
background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you want the following:

```css
#top {
  background: black;
  line-height: 39px;
}
#top nav a {
  color: #21262F;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background: green;
}
#top nav a:hover {
  background: red;
}
.onclick-menu {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.onclick-menu:after {
  content: "V";
  background: green;
  margin-left: -4px;
  padding: 8px 10px;
}
.onclick-menu:hover:after {
  background: green;
}
.onclick-menu:focus {
  outline: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.onclick-menu:focus .onclick-menu-content {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.onclick-menu-content {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #F4F4F4;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: visibility 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="top">

  <nav>
    <a href="#">Hey</a>

    <div tabindex="0" class="onclick-menu">
      <a href="#">Dropdown</a>
      <ul class="onclick-menu-content">
        <li>Look, mom</li>
        <li>no JavaScript!/li>
          <li>Pretty nice, right?</li>
      </ul>
    </div>


    <a href="#">Support</a>
  </nav>

</div>
```

For clarity's sake, this is the one:

```
.onclick-menu:hover:after {
  background: green;
}
```

I don't understand why you added `.onclick-menu` twice in that selector in the first place. It's the pseudo element of the same item, so you don't need to repeat the parent.

Comment: But now nothing happens when you hover over "V", i still want V to change color, but seperatly not when I hover over "Dropdown" though

Comment: That is not possible. Because pseudo elements are not *real* elements in the DOM, they cannot respond to events like this. If you really want behaviour like this, you'll have to add a `<span>` inside `a` with *Dropdown* in it.